# Error: number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I try to serach a lot about this stuff but I have not find anything. How can I solve the problem of 64k using Eclipse? I have different libraries, such as google play servces and I realized reading around that the major cause is due to it. I have to finish my app, is very important, How can I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a part of google play services library instead of all. For example, if you need only location add this:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'`

It helps me with 64k error.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and not android studio, how can I do this?

Comment: I did not use Eclipse. I guess you should find where you add google play services library in Eclipse and add only necessary parts instead.

Comment: Itried to procede n this way, I open the google-play-services jar, I got only the folder related to location and maps and the I recreate a new jar adding  in the previous folder where there was the the completed jar of google-play-services. Now the problem is that when in the application I calle the method to retrie the supportmapfragment the app crash sayng: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb". This seems a message about a missing class, but in the jar there is. What can I do? thanks a lot.

Comment: I just resolved, also dynamic folder had to been added in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to config your project to support multiDex

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
```

}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and not android studio, how can I do this?

Comment: why wont you use android studio though, eclipse has been deprecated